# Cordova session cookies don't work on Android Lollipop

Tags: android, ajax, cordova, cookies

I develop a Cordova/Phonegap app for Android which uses session cookies to login to third party websites.
For this, I do an AJAX post request (with jQuery) and then cookies are set automatically.

But, when I updated my smartphone to Android Lollipop 5.0 and also the app libraries to API level 21, cookies stopped working. What has changed?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

After hours spent looking on the Internet for a working solution, I came across an article that explains the issue really well, so I am posting it here because I thought it will be useful to other Stack Overflow users.

Basically, the problem lies on the new Android third party cookies policy (https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0-changes.html#BehaviorWebView), which blocks them by default.

The solutions is to add a few lines of code to the main activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.init();

    // Allow third party cookies for Android Lollipop
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        WebView webView = (WebView)super.appView;
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView,true);
    }

    super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
}
```

For more information, I put a link to the full article here: http://joashpereira.com/blog/2014/11/19/fix-to-cordovaphonegap-apps-targeting-android-5-lollipop-or-later-on-default-disallowing-third-party-cookies/

Comment: This same solution is application even if you are not using Cordova - merely using javascripts inside a webview that makes ajax calls.

Comment: This was applied by default to [Cordova Android 3.7.1](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/02/06/cordova-android-3.7.1.html), see also [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8026) and [commit](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-android.git;h=15e1948).  So take a look at your `CordovaWebView` file before using this post.

Comment: Thank you! This behavior differs from the Qt WebView I was using to build my app. It really ought to be in every introductory Android WebView tutorial nowdays since it differs from the behavior of past and other implementations.

Comment: @josemmo if we have two webviews in same activity should we declare  cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView,true); for both of them ? I want ONLY cookies of second webview be available to first webview.

Comment: @user1788736, you need to call `setAcceptThirdPartyCookies` to every WebView you want to have cookies, although I don't think that level of customization can be achieved with just this line of code. Maybe post a new question?