# Not send authentciation cookie (LtpaToken) on Android devices using IBM MF 7.0 and Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, cookies, ibm-mobilefirst, cross-domain

I am developing a MobileFirst 7.0 app and I've implemented a custom Authenticator (from the getting started samples) and LoginModule. After success login I want to use my LtpaToken to authenticate operations on Web Experience Factory services, for example I want to render content for logged user using WCM API or change some data for current logged user using Puma API. All services have url with the same domain: test.sample.com.  SSO between 2 servers is configured correctly and everything fine on iOs devices but I have a problem with Android 5.0 and above(I am testing my code only 5.0 and 5.1 Android version). I read a lot of things about problems with cookies and Android > 5.0 but no solution helped me.
1. After succss loged in MobileFirst with domain test.sample.com I got jsessionId and LtpaToken. I use this code after login and everything looks fine because my cookies exist:

```
 getSecureCookie: function() {
     _that = this;
     console.log("get secure cookie in EWD method!");
     WL.Client.getCookies().then(function(cookies) {
         for (var i in cookies) {
             console.log("test: " + i);
         }
         var ltpaToken = cookies[0];
         var test = 'LtpaToken2=' + ltpaToken.value + ' ; path=/';
         console.log("cookie_test" + test);
         _that.storage.set("LtpaToken2", test);
         console.log("ltpatokenJson: " + JSON.stringify(_that.storage.get("LtpaToken2")));
     });
 }
```

2. Then I try to call using ajax asynchronous request to WEF service that required ltpaToken and I get exception, because my user is not authenticated. When I use sniffer I see that my cookie is not attached to the request. My ajax code is shown below:

   ```
   $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.withCredentials = true;
        },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: data,
        success: success,
        error: error
    });
   ```
3. When I try to include this cookie using document.cookie it doesn't work.
4. When I try to save this cookie in localStorage and after that send it in my ajax header I get exception: "Refused to set unsafe header Cookie" and it is logical: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22481945/refused-to-set-unsafe-header-connection)
   If I try to call this service in my Chrome browser I get the same exception. But if I set "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" to "localhost" using Chrome extension everything is fine.
5. I found similar problem with Android, Phonegap and Cordova but it doesn't work for me.
   [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27579624/cordova-session-cookies-dont-work-on-android-lollipop)

My onCreate function is shown below:

```
 public class MyCompany extends CordovaActivity implements WLInitWebFrameworkListener {
    WebView wv;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //super.init();
        /*setContentView(R.layout.main);
        wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.layout.main);
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        wv.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);


        HashMap <String, String> extraHeaders = new HashMap<String, String>();
        extraHeaders.put("Cookie", "cookieName=cookieValue;domain=test.sample.com;path=/;");*/

        WL.createInstance(this);

        WL.getInstance().showSplashScreen(this);

        WL.getInstance().initializeWebFramework(getApplicationContext(), this);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.test);
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        wv.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);


        HashMap <String, String> extraHeaders = new HashMap<String, String>();
        extraHeaders.put("Cookie", "cookieName=cookieValue;domain=test.sample.com;path=/;");

        // Allow third party cookies for Android Lollipop
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
            cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
            cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(wv,true);
            cookieManager.setAcceptFileSchemeCookies(true);
            cookieManager.setCookie("test.sample.com","test=cookieValueTest;domain=test.sampme.com;path=/");
        }
        wv.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl(), extraHeaders);

    }

    /**
     * The IBM MobileFirst Platform calls this method after its initialization is complete and web resources are ready to be used.
     */
    public void onInitWebFrameworkComplete(WLInitWebFrameworkResult result){
        if (result.getStatusCode() == WLInitWebFrameworkResult.SUCCESS) {
            super.loadUrl(WL.getInstance().getMainHtmlFilePath());
        } else {
            handleWebFrameworkInitFailure(result);
        }
    }

    private void handleWebFrameworkInitFailure(WLInitWebFrameworkResult result){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton(R.string.close, new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                finish();
            }
        });

        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(R.string.error);
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(result.getMessage());
        alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false).create().show();
    }
}
```

I am using native WebView component in my hybrid app, I I try to use WebView from CordovaActivity I get exception:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method android.webkit.WebSettings android.webkit.WebView.getSettings()' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2367)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5274)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)
sed by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.webkit.WebSettings 
android.webkit.WebView.getSettings()' on a null object reference
at com.Omantel.Omantel.onCreate(Omantel.java:46)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5977)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
```

Update:
I resolved this problem and created Cordova Plugin that adds the token the WebView's:

```
@Override
public boolean execute(String action, CordovaArgs args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
    if ("INJECT-COOKIES-TO-WEBVIEW".equals(action)){
        l.debug("Started injecting cookies");

        CookieStore cookieStore = HttpClientManager.getInstance().getHttpClient().getCookieStore();
        List<Cookie> list = cookieStore.getCookies();
        for (Cookie cookie : list){
            String cookieName = cookie.getName();
            l.debug("Found cookie :: " + cookieName);
            if ("LtpaToken".equals(cookieName)){
                l.debug("Found LtpaToken cookie");
                CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
                String cookieValue = cookie.getName() + "=" + cookie.getValue();
                cookieManager.setCookie(cookie.getDomain(), cookieValue);
                break;
            }
            l.debug("LtpaToken cookie not found");
        }
        l.debug("Done injecting cookies");
        callbackContext.success();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}